# Proper usage of regex_match

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to check the format of a date string in yyyy-mm-dd format. I am calling the regex_match function like so:

```
if (regex_match(date, regex("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/")))
```

The string being passed in is exactly "1997-03-26" and when I use a regular expression tester it picks up the regular expression.

I am thinking it is something to do with regex_match and the way I am calling it but I have no idea what else it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like this:

```
"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"
```

You need the double `\\` to escape the backslash. Remember, that you have to escape it in C++, and *then* regex.

Also, the `/` is not needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! If this worked for you, go ahead and mark it as "Accepted Solution". That way, anyone else with this problem can find the answer easily :) @KyleJensen

Comment: No need to use double backslashes - when dealing with regex, one should just use raw string literals.

Comment: Two were needed, one didnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

There should be no regex delimiters here (those `/` symbols enclosing the pattern).

Also, the backslashes must be doubled in a regular string literal, however, when you work with regular expressions, it is advisable to use *raw string literals* (raw string literals are usually formed with the help of `R"(` and then `)"` enclosing sequences where `(` and `)` can be also replace with some other delimiters).

So, you can use

```
#include<regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool found = regex_match("1997-03-26",regex(R"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"));
    cout<<(found?"found":"not found");
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/KpMDJq)

Mind that `regex_match` requires a whole string match! Otherwise, for partial matches, use `regex_search`.

Comment: Can you explain this further? I implemented this and it didnt work

Comment: I have provided a whole demo. Please check and let me know if anything is still not clear.

Comment: I am sorry for slow response, I am on a laptop and it is inconvenient.

Comment: Hi Kyle, are there any further issues?